# Estimate of cumulative probability of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_\tau$ be the standard BM, $t$ be the initial time, $s$ be the time variable, $r$ and $\theta$ are positive constants. We also assume that $x$ is the initial position of the below geometric Brownian motion and $a>0$ be some constant. I would like to estimate the lower bound of $$\mathbb{P}\left( x\exp\left[ (r-\dfrac{\theta^2}{2})(s-t) + \theta(B_s-B_t)\right] \leq a\right).$$
I know that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(  B_s-B_t
\leq a \right) \geq 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{2(s-t)}}{2a} \exp \left(-\dfrac{a^2}{2(s-t)} \right).$$
I have tried to apply the above fact and take log in the original form. But I found that the inequality is quite complicated. Do we have some clean estimate for this type of stuff?

Comment: So $B_t$ is (additive) Brownian motion or (multiplicative) geometric Brownian motion? With mean drift $0$ and volatility $\sigma$? And you want the probability of its being below a certain level at the time $s$?

Comment: $B_\tau$ is the standard Brownian motion and $x\exp\left[ (r-\dfrac{\theta^2}{2})(s-t) + \theta(B_s-B_t)\right]$ is the geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: So the probability is $\mathbb{P}[\theta B_s \le \theta B_t + \ln(a/x) - (r-\theta^2/2)(s-t)]$, which is $\Phi[(B_t + \ln(a/x))/\theta)/\sqrt{s-t} - (r/\theta -\theta/2)\sqrt{s-t}]$. Then there is a large literature on bounds and approximations for $\Phi$, because none of them are especially clean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF_and_normal_quantile_function

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!